# Compiler flags Pybind11

Tags: mingw, pybind11

I am building an application using Pybind11. I am using the following setup.py to build my module:

```
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension, build_ext
from setuptools import setup

__version__ = "0.0.1"

ext_modules = [
    Pybind11Extension("surface_mesh",
                      ["src/surface_mesh.cpp",
                       ],
                      include_dirs=["include", "../../include"],
                      define_macros = [('VERSION_INFO', __version__)],
                      ),
]

setup(
    name="surface_mesh",
    version=__version__,
    author="Hein Hachmann",
    author_email="schorf@gmx.de",
    description="Surface mesh module",
    long_description="",
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
    zip_safe=False,
    python_requires=">=3.7",
)
```

When I run it, I get the following invocation:

```
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -march=nocona -msahf -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -march=nocona -msahf -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -IC:\msys64\mingw64\include\python3.10 -c flagcheck.cpp -o flagcheck.o -std=c++17
```

1.) What mechanism generates this sequence of compiler flags? I'm assuming it is the `Pybind11Extension` module? When I look at the source code for Pybind11Extension, I do not find the flags, so I do not understand where they come from.

2.) I have the feeling my code could run faster. I am seeing a couple -O2 in the compiler command line. How can I change that to -O3?

Comment: The difference between `-O2` to `-O3` is not very large. I'd try to profile your code first to see why your code is slow.

Comment: That may be, and I agree, but I would really like to know how to get control over those flags and where they're coming from in the first place.